# SQLite: unable to open database the first time, not the second?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, crash

I'm using SQLite with C# and I start by creating a database file with System.IO:

```
System.IO.File.Create(directoryLineEdit.Text + @"\" + nameLineEdit.Text + ".db");
```

Now, I try to open this newly created database: (where **location** is the path to where the file is stored, don't mind the **path** parameter, that is not relevant here)

```
public void loadSpaceWalls(string path, string location)
{
    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + location))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (SQLiteCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';";
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            Godot.Collections.Array wallsArray = new Godot.Collections.Array();

            while (rdr.Read())
                wallsArray.Add(rdr[0]);

            rdr.Close();
            GetNode(path).Call("updateSpaceWalls", wallsArray);
            wallsArray.Dispose();
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

The program crashes with `System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (0x800007FF): unable to open database file`. Now, if I re-open my program and then access the file again (the same code, only difference is that the file has not been 'newly created' by the program, it already exists now), it works fine and doesn't crash.

This does puzzle me 
Any ideas as to why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.Create` returns a `FileStream`, which is left open. Unless you're disposing of that stream, nothing else will be able to open the file.

So I *suspect* all you need to do is change your code to something like:

```cs
string dbPath = Path.Combine(directoryLineEdit.Text, $"{nameLineEdit.Text}.db");
using (File.Create(dbPath))
{
    // No-op - we just want to create the file and immediately close the stream.
}
```